# place an ad on top of layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

Mobile **ad** does not get positioned on the **top of the layout** ,like the **ad** placed at the **bottom** .It is not **overlapping** the layout.

here is the image of the layout,and what i am talking about,have a look
[Image of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBWTt.png)

here is the **xml code** for it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.dancing.dance.girl"
    android:background="@mipmap/vsdv">


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/abovebeauty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/dancinggirl">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>



    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:id="@+id/beauty_fragment"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/lob"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"


                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/lob"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"


                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />




        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/lob"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/3"

                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />



            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/lob"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/4"

                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/beautyfragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/dancinggirl">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Thankyou for looking at it.**

Comment: Add `android:layout_below="abovebeauty"` in your `beauty_fragment` LinearLayout

Comment: use frameLayout

Comment: @Ankur have you seen the image ?,i need it to overlap, like the ad which is placed at bottom of the screen in the image.

Comment: @Saravlnfern i had tried to use it but can't find the solution,let me know the code for it which you are trying to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.dancing.dance.girl"
android:background="@mipmap/vsdv">






<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:id="@+id/beauty_fragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/lob"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"


            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/lob"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"


            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />




    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/lob"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/3"

            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />



        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/lob"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/4"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/abovebeauty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/dancinggirl">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/beautyfragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/dancinggirl">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put Ad layout below LinearLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.dancing.dance.girl"
android:background="@mipmap/vsdv">


<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:id="@+id/beauty_fragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/lob"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"


            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/lob"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"


            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />




    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/lob"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/3"

            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />



        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/lob"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/4"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/beautyfragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/dancinggirl">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/abovebeauty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/dancinggirl">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: you posted same answer as mine -_-

Comment: So? It is the right solution and i also wrote on same time

Comment: you wrote 2 minutes late than me